# If you decided, felt, etc in the past before something happened, does it become Past Perfect?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, tenses

For instance, a girl is talking about her past. For example,

> when I was enrolled at a graduate school I needed money so I set up a small business. But I earned so much money that I decided to leave school. [...] Then I felt a strong need to leave that business and start a new one.

For the words "set up", "decide" and "feel" what tense would be correct here?

Comment: They sound fine to me.

Comment: The simple past, as you have written it, is fine in a narrative of this kind. You only need the pluperfect (past perfect) where you are describing a past event in relation to another more recent past event e.g. *I had already eaten dinner, when they arrived*. But @Shoe provides an excellent comprehensive answer below.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because I don't understand what you're asking. Could you give sentence for the [...], please?

Answer (score 2):

For simple narratives about past events, the default tense is the *past simple*. Each of the verbs in the text below is correctly in the past simple, and the sequence of events is clear.

> When I *was* enrolled at a graduate school I *needed* money so I *set*
>   up a small business. But I *earned* so much money that I *decided* to
>   leave school. Then I *felt* a strong need to leave that business  ...
>   .

The past perfect is much less common in such narratives, but may be used at certain points to lay greater emphasis on the fact that one event preceded or followed another. Typically, the words *before* and *after* are used in such contexts:

> *After* I *had earned* enough money, I decided to leave that business.
>
> She got up from the table *before I had finished* eating.

The past perfect is sometimes required to make the sequence of events clear. For example, compare the following:

> When I arrived at the meeting, John *left*. (past simple: *he left after
>   I arrived*)
>
> When I arrived at the meeting, John had left. (past perfect: *he left
>   before I arrived*)

The past perfect is also commonly used in utterances of reported speech or thought:

> I asked her if she *had eaten* yet.
>
> He wondered if he *had remembered* to lock the door.
>
> I wish you *had told* me you couldn't come.

In summary, you need a specific reason to use the past perfect. And there is no reason to use it for any of the verbs in your passage.